# when to use vibrating platforms

Tags: weightlifting, workout-routines

There is one of these vibrating platforms at the gym and a chart with different positions to exercise different body parts (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whole_body_vibration).

I would like to combine this platform exercises for legs and back with the standard 30 minutes x-trainer plus weights that I do every day. I split my weights sessions usually into 3 different days.

What would be the best combination for the vibration platform exercises together with the x-trainer and weights sessions I am doing?

Comment: My opinion is that you get more results with traditional strength training than you do with fancy vibration machines.

Answer (score 4):

During my studies I participated in an experiment where we had to maintain squats off varying degrees on and off a vibrating platform. They compared our heart rate and oxygen uptake, to see if it had any effect.

I believe the idea was that when you're in a deep squat, the blood flow in your legs gets occluded due to the pressure of the tensed muscles on your arteries. Here's a [similar, published study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19125731). Because of the occlusion, you would start to fatigue, because your muscles don't get enough oxygen and thus have to work anaerobically.

The results of the study showed no advantage when using the vibrating platform, which has been the result of other (independent) studies as well. As a disclaimer, my university got sued by Powerplate, because they published some studies claiming vibrating plates didn't work, so you can understand my skepticism. However, other groups published results [that were more positive](http://www.comfitsolutions.com/yahoo_site_admin/assets/docs/WBV_-_Versus_Resistance_Training.13001634.pdf).

Either way, as Berin commented: you can get great results using traditional strength training, so you simply shouldn't need vibrating platforms

Comment: Right now I am using it for series of 30 seconds after I have done my x-trainer series. It seems to get my legs ready for weight lifting, but this is more a subjective feeling than anything. I would be interested in people's comments on this.

Comment: I personally don't think it would be helpful that way, I believe it would be intended to perform workouts while on it. Its effect on recovery are probably neglible, but if it makes you feel good, don't let me stop you

Comment: We performed a study where the subject performed a vertical jump without a warm up. They rested for 5 minutes and then stood on a vibrating plate for varying intervals. After each vibrating interval they were then asked to jump as high as they could again. We actually found that anything over 20 seconds and less than a 80 seconds had no effect on the jump; but, did improve the jump by and average of 3.5 inches. After 80 seconds the subjects either jumped the same height or less.

Answer (score 3):

One of the good uses that I'm aware of for vibrating platforms is during rehabilitation. I had an Achilles tendon surgically repaired last year, and extended time with absolutely no calf activity left it atrophied.

During rehabilitation (for my injury and other lower limb injuries), the plate was used to stand on and do various bodyweight exercises (With appropriate railing support) to increase the muscle activation and workload.

However, for an able bodied person, I think it would actually detract from the exercise, as you are concentrating on balance more than the exercise form, and you lose whatever you might be gaining because of a less effective lift. There are very few lifts (swiss ball exercises notwithstanding) that I am aware of where you want a less stable platform.